# Removing empty space of ExtJS cycle-button possible?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

The cycle button has some empty space in front of the text they show, probably because the menu items can have icons, is it possible to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either display:none the "x-btn-icon" for the control, or use the "iconAlign" property inside of your config to move the icon div to the right of the control label.

Answer (score 0):

Apply css to solve the problem,

{
white-space: normal; 
}

Thanks

Comment: didn't work. the space in front of the cycle button is probably left free for icons, but I don't need icons, and even setting the icon to '' doesn't help :\